# Convert google maps timezone to GMT string using javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm getting a string representing a timezone from google maps API,

the string looks like that: `'Asia/Damascus'`.

I want to convert it to a string that looks like that: `GMT +01:00`.

Any Ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this library [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).Alternatively if you are using google maps timezone API[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro) you should also get a rawOffset (diff from UTC) which you can use to manually calculate what you want also

Comment: Great, thanks. do you have any clue how can I convert the rawOffset to what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I did this:

```
import momentTimeZone from 'moment-timezone';
import moment from 'moment';

const getGmtFromTimeZone = ({ timeZone = '' } = {}) =>  {

   if (!timeZone) {
       return null;
   }

   const zone = momentTimeZone.tz.zone(timeZone);
   const gmtOffSet = zone.parse(new Date());
   const hour = moment.utc((Math.abs(gmtOffSet) * 60) * 1000).format('HH:mm');

   return `GMT${gmtOffSet > 0 ? '-' : '+'}${hour}`;
}
```